# Type that contains all functions of N elements in Coq

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I am learning Coq and as an exercise I want to define a type `FnArity (N:nat)` to encode *all* functions of `N` arguments. That is:

```
Check FnArity 3 : (forall A B C : Set, A -> B -> C).
```

Should work but

```
Check FnArity 2 : (forall A B C D : Set, A -> B -> C -> D).
```

Should not work.

This is for pedagogic purposes so any relevant resources are welcome.

EDIT: From the answers so far I realize I am probably approaching this wrong so here is the proposition I am trying to prove: 
Composing N composition operators is equivalent to a composition operator that composes `f` and `g` where `g` expects N arguments. In haskell-ish terms:

```
(.).(.) ... N times ... (.).(.) f g = \a1, .. aN -> f (g (a1, .. , aN))
```

EDIT2: In coq terms:

```
Definition compose { A B C : Type } (F : C -> B) (G : A -> C ) : A -> B :=
  fun x => F ( G (x) ).

Definition compose2 {A1 A2 B C : Type} (F : C -> B) (G : A1 -> A2 -> C)
: A1 -> A2 -> B := fun x y => F ( G x y ).

Definition compose3 {A1 A2 A3 B C : Type} (F : C -> B) (G : A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> C)
: A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> B := fun x y z => F ( G x y z ).

(* The simplest case *)
Theorem dual_compose : forall {A B C D : Type} (f: D -> C) (g : A -> B -> D) ,
                         (compose compose compose) f g = compose2 f g.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.

Theorem triple_compose : forall {A1 A2 A3 B C : Type} (f: C -> B) (g : A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> C) ,
                         (compose (compose (compose) compose) compose) f g =
                         compose3 f g.
```

What I want is to define the generalized theorem for `composeN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types that you wrote down do not quite represent what you stated in your problem: `forall A B C, A -> B -> C` is not the type of all functions of three arguments, but the type of certain polymorphic functions of two arguments. You probably meant to write something like `{ A & { B & { C & A -> B -> C }}}` instead, where `A`, `B` and `C` are *existentially* quantified. You probably also meant to say `Compute (FnArity 3)` instead of using the `Check` command, since the latter is the one that evaluates a term (and, as jbapple pointed out, no term can have the type that you had originally written).

Here's a piece of code that does what you want, I think. We start by writing a function `FnArityAux1 : list Type -> Type -> Type`, that computes a function type with arguments given on a list:

```
Fixpoint FnArityAux1 (args : list Type) (res : Type) : Type :=
  match args with
  | [] => res
  | T :: args' => T -> FnArityAux1 args' res
  end.
```

For instance, `FnArityAux1 [nat; bool] bool` evaluates to `nat -> bool -> bool`. We can then use this function to define `FnArity` as follows:

```
Fixpoint FnArityAux2 (args : list Type) (n : nat) : Type :=
  match n with
  | 0 => { T : Type & FnArityAux1 args T }
  | S n' => { T : Type & FnArityAux2 (args ++ [T]) n' }
  end.

Definition FnArity n := FnArityAux2 [] n.
```

In this definition, we use another auxiliary function `FnArityAux2` that has an argument `args` whose purpose is to carry around all the existentially quantified types produced so far. For each "iteration step", it quantifies over another type `T`, adds that type to the list of arguments, and recurses. When the recursion is over, we use `FnArityAux1` to combine all accumulated types into a single function type. Then, we can define `FnArity` simply by starting the process with an empty list -- that is, no quantified types at all.

Comment: You indeed seem to answer my question but I couldn't make the derived type work for my problem. Could you check my edit and amend your answer commenting on it?

Comment: @fakedrake In this case, you probably just need the type `FnArityAux1`. I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Also what does the `&` symbol mean. I assume it is some kind of infix existential quantifier but I couldn't find documentation about it?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, since `(forall A B C : Set, A -> B -> C)` is uninhabited.

```
Goal (forall A B C : Set, A -> B -> C) -> False.
intros f.
specialize (f True True False).
apply f; trivial.
Qed.
```

As such, `Check FnArity 3 : (forall A B C : Set, A -> B -> C).` can never work.